# Celery task group not being executed in background and results in exception

Tags: python, django, celery

My Celery task isn't executing in the background in my Django 1.7/Python3 project.

```
# settings.py

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULTBACKEND = BROKER_URL
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
```

I have `celery.py` in my root app module as such:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('my_app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

and load the app in `__init__.py` in the root module:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

My task is set up as a shared task in a tasks.py file in my app module:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def update_statistics(profile, category):
    # more code
```

and I call the task as a group:

```
. . .
job = group([update_statistics(f.profile, category)
          for f in forecasts])
job.apply_async()
```

However, I'm not seeing any status updates in my task queue, which I am starting via:

```
$ celery -A my_app worker -l info
```

The task *is* being executed, just not in the background. If I add a print statement to the task code, I will see the output in my Django development server console instead of the Celery queue.

After the task runs in the foreground, I'm greeted with this exception:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Here's the full traceback if you're interested: https://gist.github.com/alsoicode/0263d251e3744227ba46

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling the tasks directly in your list comprehension when you create the group, so they're executed then and there. You need to use the `.subtask()` method (or its shortcut, `.s()`) to create the subtasks without calling them:

```
job = group([update_statistics.s(f.profile, category) for f in forecasts])
```

Comment: You sir, are the man. I'm not sure how I missed than in the documentation, but it works as expected. Upvote and accept coming shortly. Thank you very much!